# Django site_media relative url problem

Tags: css, django, django-urls

in my settings.py I have the following:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'templates')
MEDIA_URL = '/templates/'
```

In urls.py I have `(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),`

And my base.html has the following directive:

```
<link media="screen" href="site_media/bat/design/css/bat.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Upon first entry into the application (i.e. http://localhost) this stylesheet gets loaded just fine.  However, on a subsequent http request (in urls.py it is `(r'^assist/bat/', include('assist.bat.urls'))`, to another template this directive results in the following error:

> The stylesheet http://localhost/assist/bat/site_media/bat/design/css/bat.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css."

As you can see, this css directive gets morphed into a relative url which is completely incorrect.  If I remove **/assist/bat** from that url, then it works just fine.  So how can I set up my app to not morph url's this way?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess: `href="site_media/bat/design/css/bat.css"` should be `href="/site_media/bat/design/css/bat.css"`, urls starting without slash in front of them are resolved relatively to the current url.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, that did it.  I actually found this thread on Google which discusses a similar problem: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/0f50284640b855d3?pli=1

I think I get it now.